# SPFX App is not installed and does not uninstalls from webapplication

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I have deployed a SPFX app on the on-prem SharePoint 2019 server but it is not reflecting on the web application

Version of SPFX 1.1

The add an app page of the web application also shows the message "**Apps are not enabled**" on this server.

Also I have noticed that **Subscriptions Settings Service Application** is not running on the server, is it required for SPFX solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to deploy SPFx apps, you must enable:

- Subscriptions Settings Service Application
- App Management Service Application

Also, an `App catalog site` (App > Manage App Catalog) had to be created.

[image: Subscriptions Settings Service Application]
[image: App Management Service Application]

You can automate the initial provisioning by PowerShell:

```
$sssa = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication -ApplicationPool "SharePoint Web Services Default" -Name "Subscriptions Settings Service Application" -DatabaseName "SP_AppSubscription"
New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $sssa


$account = Get-SPManagedAccount "AD\service-account"    
$appPoolAppSvc = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name "AppServiceAppPool" -Account $account
$appAppSvc = New-SPAppManagementServiceApplication -ApplicationPool $appPoolAppSvc -Name "SP_AppServiceApp" -DatabaseName "SP_AppServiceApp"
New-SPAppManagementServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $appAppSvc

(Get-SPServiceInstance | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq "App Management Service"}).Provision()
```